# how to install React-Native NPM packages?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

I am install React-Native project with this code:

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

This project is located in desktop and I want install `react-native-card-stack`   from `npm`.

Then I input this code on command prompt:

```
npm install --save react-native-card-stack
```

When I check `cd /desktop/AwesomeProject`  here in ide of  `node_modules` I can't find `react-native-card-stack`

My question is, where can I run `npm install --save react-native-card-stack node_modules`?

Appreciate your guys help.

Comment: You have to run it in your projects root folder (where the package.json) is

Comment: thank you wait ill check and tell

Comment: i got a error '~/Desktop/my app/abbc# react-native link
Scanning folders for symlinks in /root/Desktop/my app/abbc/node_modules (11ms)

`react-native link` can not be used in Create React Native App projects. If you need to include a library that relies on custom native code, you might have to eject first. See https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md for more information.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start from first

Step 1
Open terminal and type:

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

Step 2
Once the project is created  it will show list of options : type command

```
cd AwesomeProject
```

Step 3
Add the package

```
npm install --save react-native-card-stack
```

Step 4 
Run the project

```
npm start
```

That is all you need to do. Now you can scan from your expo app to run the project in your phone directly.

Note if the app shows error while running run `npm install`

Comment: i got this error 
'Unable to resolve react" from ".//node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js" '